# Pass arguments for SQL statement in a shell file from another shell file through ssh command

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, shell, ssh

I am passing command line arguments to a shell file i.e assignRole.sh which contains an SQL command which will use these arguments like below

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T $key < /oracle/oracle_user/makhshif/./assignRole.sh name open_mode >> /oracle/oracle_user/dftest.txt
```

This gives me error and does not accept arguments of **name** and **open_mode** and gives error, but if I execute the statement outside of ssh command like:

```
/oracle/oracle_user/makhshif/./assignRole.sh name open_mode
```

This runs fine

What is the problem with ssh command and how should I adjust these parameters so these can be accepted for the shell script assignRole.sh

Answer (score 1):

```
 < /oracle/oracle_user/makhshif/./assignRole.sh
```

This commands sends a content of that file to stdin. So obviously it can't process variables that you haven't send to remote machine. Just preprocess your script or create a script on remote machine and call it with arguments

Though it's even easier to pass variables like this:

```sh
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T $key "var1=$var1 var2=$var2" < /oracle/oracle_user/makhshif/./assignRole.sh name open_mode >> /oracle/oracle_user/dftest.txt
```

For example my function for executing update scripts on all cluster nodes:

```sh
# functions:
ssh_exec(){
  local DESCR="$1"; shift
  local SCRIPT="$1"; shift
  local hosts=("$@")
  echo =================================================
  echo =   $DESCR
  echo = Going to execute $SCRIPT...
  read -a res -p "Enter 'skip' to skip this step or press Enter to execute: "
  if [[ $res = "skip" ]]
  then
    echo Skipping $SCRIPT...
  else
    echo Executing $SCRIPT...
    for host in "${hosts[@]}"
        do
          local cur=${!host}
          echo Executing $SCRIPT on $host - $cur...
          sshpass -p "$rootpass" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@${cur} \
            "ns1=$ns1 ns2=$ns2 search=$search zoo1=$zoo1 zoo2=$zoo2 zoo3=$zoo3 node0=$node0 pass=$pass CURIP=$cur CURHOST=$host bash -s" \
            <$SCRIPT >log-$SCRIPT-$cur.log 2>&1
          echo Done.
        done
    echo =================================================
  fi
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
read -p "Please check that Solr started successfully and Press [Enter] key to continue..."

#Solr configset and collections:
ssh_exec "Solr configset and collections" script06.sh zoo1 zoo2 zoo3
```

This command executes `script06.sh` on 3 servers (zoo1,zoo2,zoo3)

Comment: assignRole.sh is on remote machine, I want arguments to be accepted for this file in ssh command so the assignRole.sh on remote machine can use these for sql content inside it

Comment: @user3102917 no, `<path_to_file` reads file from your local machine, not remote!

Comment: it reads file from you local machine (where you are executing `ssh` and sends it to stdin on a remote machine. And you can pass variables as I showed: `"var1=123 var2=$v1 var3=$v2"`  before `<`

Comment: ah, I understood now... Just don't use `<`

Answer (score 0):

As Sayan said, using `<` redirects the output of running the `assignRole.sh` script locally, but you want to execute that script on the remote host, with the arguments.

Pass the whole command as the final argument to `ssh`, in quotes:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T $key "/oracle/oracle_user/makhshif/./assignRole.sh name open_mode" >> /oracle/oracle_user/dftest.txt
```

or split into multiple lines for readability:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T $key \ 
  "/oracle/oracle_user/makhshif/./assignRole.sh name open_mode" \
  >> /oracle/oracle_user/dftest.txt
```

Comment: In that case it says 
role.sh: line 70: /oracle/oracle_user/makhshif/./assignRole.sh name open_mode: No such file or directory

and if I copy the part /oracle/oracle_user/makhshif/./assignRole.sh name open_mode, it runs fine when executed

Comment: When you run it manually are you doing that locally or remotely - does that script exist in that location on the remote machine?

Comment: Manually I run it locally and it brings result from remote server
, The script only exists locally, what I want is. 
1) SSH to that server
2) Run this local SQL script on remote server after taking command line arguments  and bring the result here

Comment: What is "remote" and "local" for you? Is that script where you run `ssh` command or not?

Comment: local is where I run script. ssh command is in this local script which calls another local script i.e assignroles.sh and tries passing arguments in it which have to be passed to an SQL statement in assignRoles.sh and this SQL needs to execute on remote server being accessed in ssh command

Comment: I think you really need to edit your question and explain the topography - where each element lives and will be executed, including where the sqlplus executable lives and where the database sits, and how/why ssh is involved. It's a bit unclear and confusing at the moment.